# Is there a way to have an excel cell contain multiple values in the filter function?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Here is a mockup of the table I am trying to build.
Is it possible for the right most column to have its cells contain multiple values ?
As in, I could be able to select a student name in the filter to make pop up all the class this specific student has missed.

[image]

I tried to use the "contain" filter but i have to write again the student name every time as the modalities of the columns become the list of absent student for each classes.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried reading your question two times, but I must confess I cannot understand what you want doing. If the picture you show is what you want accomplishing (at least, this is what I'm supposing), how does the table where you try extracting what you show show? I mean, a picture with the initial situation should help. If I also missed the existing picture signification, please better explain what you need doing, starting from an initial  situation, to reach a another specific one.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. You need to type a name and use contains filter. You could do better with VBA but that's not what you asked for

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data sample **AS TEXT** from which your desired results table was derived. It looks like something that can be done easily in VBA or Power Query, or with some of the newer Excel 365 functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work with a little VBA;

Setup the sheet like below with a cell (in green) in which to select a student name from a drop down (data validation) and a button to click to implement the filtering

[image]

Then name the button as GoButn and add the code below to the Sheet

```
Private Sub GoButn_Click()
   Dim SrchFor As String
   
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
   SrchFor = "*" & Trim(Range("G2").Text) & "*"
   ActiveSheet.Range("MissingPPL").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=SrchFor, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

In the above code the Green cell is "G2" and the Table has been named "MissingPPL"

Example below of selecting Jill and clicking Go

[image]

Hope this helps